# TeamCity parameter specification referring to another parameter?

Tags: teamcity

I am using the latest version of TeamCity and I am trying to make a parameter specification that refers to parameters.

I tried making a select (combobox), where the options of the checkbox are referring to variables. **This should be possible, as there is a "parameter" icon to the right of the box suggesting me that I can use parameters here.**

The full setup is shown below.

[image]

However, when I want to run the build, the only options are *literally* `%foo%` and `%bar%` as if the parameters have not even been evaluated.

Instead I had expected the options to contain the *values of the variables that they are pointing to*.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late, but this is how I did it:

I have a few parameters for holding passwords, e.g. 'mfgpwd'

[image]

And I refer to these in another parameter using the syntax:

mfgpwd=%system.mfgpwd%

(I'm using TeamCity 8.1.5)